Actix-Web JWT middleware
I'm building a web application using Actix-web and I'm trying to secure my endpoints with JWT (JSON Web Token) middleware. However, it seems that the middleware isn't working correctly, as my protected endpoints are still accessible without a valid token.
Here is my code
JWT middleware
use actix_web::{dev::{Service, ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse, Transform}, web, Error, HttpMessage};
use futures::future::{ok, LocalBoxFuture, Ready};
use std::{rc::Rc, sync::Arc};
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

use crate::{libs::jwt::verify_jwt, AppState};

pub struct JwtAuthMiddleware {
    state: web::Data<AppState>,
}

impl JwtAuthMiddleware {
    pub fn new(state: web::Data<AppState>) -> Self {
        Self { state }
    }
}

impl<S, B> Transform<S, ServiceRequest> for JwtAuthMiddleware
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Transform = JwtAuthMiddlewareInner<S>;
    type InitError = ();
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(JwtAuthMiddlewareInner {
            service: Rc::new(service),
            state: self.state.clone(),
        })
    }
}

pub struct JwtAuthMiddlewareInner<S> {
    service: Rc<S>,
    state: web::Data<AppState>,
}

impl<S, B> Service<ServiceRequest> for JwtAuthMiddlewareInner<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = LocalBoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    fn poll_ready(&self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.service.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let service = self.service.clone();
        let state = self.state.clone();
        let (http_request, payload) = req.into_parts();

        let fut = async move {
            match verify_jwt(&http_request, &state).await {
                Ok(claims) => {
                    let req = ServiceRequest::from_parts(http_request, payload);
                    req.extensions_mut().insert(Arc::new(claims));
                    service.call(req).await
                }
                Err(_) => Err(actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Unauthorized")),
            }
        };

        Box::pin(fut)
    }
}

route
pub fn route(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig, state: web::Data<AppState>) {
    cfg.service(
        web::scope("/api/v1/customers")
            .route("/register", web::post().to(create_customer))
            .route("/login", web::post().to(signin_customer))
            .route("/block/{id}", web::get().wrap(JwtAuthMiddleware::new(state.clone())).to(block_customer_controller))
    );
}

Main
.configure(|cfg| app::customers::routes::route::route(cfg, state.clone()))

the middleware doesn't seem to run
Help would be much appreciated

Are you sure it doesn't run? If you print inside it, does it output?

No It doesn't outpit

Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example. In particular, since you say the middleware doesn't run, post a complete, runnable snippet (ideally in one file) that contains only one route, with an empty middleware except for a println!(), so we can copy the code, run it and observe it does not run.

I finally figured it out.
.route(
     "/block/{id}", 
      web::get().to(block_customer_controller)
      .wrap(CheckUserMiddleware::new(state.clone()))
      .wrap(JwtAuthMiddleware::new(state.clone()))
),

Had to call the wrap after setting the method and controller

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
